# Downloads, Shown in notification bar?

Tags: android, xml, multithreading, notifications, android-asynctask

As far as I know we can create notifications in Android using Notification Manager + remote Views.

I am Creating a notification for downloading Mp3 files. And I want an animations beside It. So far I have learned from forums that it is not possible.

However I saw A video for an android App which downloads and displays animation beside it while downloading it. Link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNcs-sS2nFU&feature=related

Moreover its the same animation used by the browser. How can they do it?

If any one suggests using level drawable for me, Please also suggest still I have to send a whole remote View to the notification manager with the same Notification ID. It will override it. That gives a animation like thing if I do it again and again. Is there no way to update remoteviews without sending the changed remoteviews to Notification manager.

WHY, I dont want the above mentioned animation effect?
Because It hangs the android. If the updates are sent more faster then 2000ms.

This question is also asked elsewhere at stackoverflow but never been answered.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to all our problems,

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

There is a built in download manager in android.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that particular animation you are seeing (the downward moving arrow) is provided by the system.  I don't think you will be able to place your own custom animation in a standard notification.